# MongoError: failed to connect to server [mongo:27017] on first connect

Tags: mongodb, docker

Docker config:

```
FROM node:8
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Docker compose:

```
version: "2"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    depends_on:
    - mongo
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    ports:
    - "27017:27017"
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "docker_web_app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "author": "Stepan Yakovenko <stiv.yakovenko@gmail.com>",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {"express": "^4.16.1","mongodb": "~3.0.1","monk": "~6.0.5" }
}
```

server.js:

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var monk = require('monk');
var db = monk('mongo:27017/nodetest1');
db.then(function(){console.log("hello"});
```

Most of the time it works, but if I purge docker cache, usually it doesn't work and gives me this:

```
web_1    | (node:15) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: failed to connect to server [mongo:27017] on first connect [MongoErr
or: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.18.0.2:27017]
```

The root cause I think that docker's *depends_on* doesn't guarantee me that mongo has started listening, because in this case I get listening message from mongo after this error. How can I fix this? Does docker has any fix for this situation? Or how can I ask mongo to try connecting forever?

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is sample reconnect code, which worked for me:

```
var connect = function () {
    var db = monk('mongo:27017/nodetest1');
    db.then(function () {
        console.log("connected");
    }).catch(function () {
        // sometimes node starts before mongo, so we have to reconnect in case of error
        connect();
    });
};
connect();
```